# Mimetype --stdin always returns text/plain

Tags: linux, debian, mime-types

I am having a hard time getting the correct mimetype info without relaying on the file extension / inode data. When using magic it returns with text/plain ever time regardless of what the file is.

For some background information.

When I allow linux mimetype to use glob and its other methods it works correctly.

`mimetype  mountain.jpg`

> mountain.jpg: image/jpeg

When I try to have it work with magic checking because i want to really make sure this file is an image it tells me its a text file

`mimetype -M mountain.jpg`

> mountain.jpg: image/jpeg

To make sure its not a text file I will use the file command

`file -i  mountain.jpg`

> mountain.jpg: image/jpeg; charset=binary

If i try one of the following I will now only be able to get text/plain.

`cat mountain_dew-400-400.jpg | mimetype -M --stdin`

> STDIN: text/plain

`tee mountain_dew-400-400.jpg | mimetype -M --stdin`

> STDIN: text/plain

`mimetype --stdin - < mountain_dew-400-400.jpg`

> STDIN: text/plain

I have already run the following commands

```
cpan install IO::Scalar
cpan install File::MimeInfo
cpan install File::MimeInfo::Magic
```

Comment: `inode/x-empty` sounds like an empty file. Add the output of `ls -l mountain.jpg` to your question.

Comment: @user49740 fiuxed copy and paste errors that casued pafrt of issue but still getting the other part

Comment: I see the same problem over here. Try `file -i -` instead of `mimetype --stdin`.

Comment: Bug reported to the Debian BTS: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784545

Comment: Thanks for submitting a bug report on that. also file -i - seems to work i assumed it did not take a pipe since it was not listed in the man page. If you want to submit the full answer i will give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mimetype --stdin` does not appear to work at all. I've submitted [Debian bug #784545](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784545).

As a workaround you can use `file -i -` instead of `mimetype --stdin`.